# Getting minimum value from database and randomising order in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of offer prices for theatre shows. There may be more than one offer for each show, but I'm trying to pull a random 6 that have the lowest price. There may be around 20-odd shows with about 3 offers on each show and I'd like the lowest price for 6 unique random shows.

I can easily find the lowest prices using ORDER BY `price`, but that means I can't use ORDER BY RAND() in order to mix them up. I suspect I need to do a UNION or something, but can't get my head around it.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `offers` GROUP BY `showID` ORDER BY `price` LIMIT 6
```

That gets the 6 lowest prices, and the GROUP ensures it's 6 different shows, but always the same 6 shows. If I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `offers` GROUP BY `showID` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

I get 6 random shows, but not necessarily the lowest price. How do I combine these to get both lowest price and random results?

Edit to add requested Sample Data:

```
id | showID | offer          | price
1  | 1234   | 10% Off Band A | 15.00
2  | 1234   | 15% Off Band B | 25.00
3  | 4321   | 10% Off Band B | 20.00
4  | 1234   | 25% Off Band C | 30.00
5  | 6666   | Free Upgrade   | 13.00
6  | 6666   | Premium Seats  | 40.00
7  | 4321   | Half Price     | 12.00
```

Not a full data sample, but in the above example there are three unique shows, so I'd want ids 1, 5 & 7 as the cheapest offers for those shows, but returned in a random order. In the full dataset there's about 20 unique shows with multiple offers and I just want a random six of them.

Comment: please put the sample data in your question

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. However, if I were you I'd implement this in application logic, rather than trying to cram it all into a query, if only for readability.

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE id IN (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT id 
     FROM offers 
     WHERE showID = show_ids.showID 
     AND price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM offers WHERE showID = show_ids.showID)
     LIMIT 1) offer_id
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT showID 
    FROM offers 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
  ) show_ids
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In [MySQL 8.0.2 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/), we can utilize [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). However for older versions, one approach is possible using [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). It is basically a sub-Select query, in which we will identify 6 Random `showID` values to consider.

Now, we need the complete row corresponding to the lowest price. So, in another Derived table, we will determine the lowest Price for a `showID`.

We will then simply need to **Join** these result-set to the main table to get the rows corresponding to the lowest price for 6 random `showID` values.

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM offers AS o 
JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT showID FROM offers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6) AS dt1 
  ON dt1.showID = o.showID 
JOIN 
  (SELECT showID, MIN(price) AS min_price FROM offers GROUP BY showID) AS dt2 
  ON dt2.showID = o.showID AND 
     dt2.min_price = o.price
```